# Loop over and count columns in a data frame until condition is met

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to loops in R (and to stack overflow!)

I have a `data.frame` for which columns `5:19` ask about the gender of household members (member 1, member 2, member 3 etc).

If, for example, a person only has 2 other household members, the values will be `NA` (represented by a negative number) for member 3 gender onwards (columns `7:19`).

Using a `for-loop`, I would like to use these variables to derive a total `household_size`-variable.

My thinking was to make a household size variable and then add 1 for every column in `5:19` until hitting a column where the value is a negative number.

```
#start with 1 for the respondent themselves 

DF$HHSIZE<-1

  for (i in DF[,5:19]){
  if_else (i>0, DF$HHSIZE<-DF$HHSIZE+1, break) 
  }
```

I am doing something wrong here because the value for everyone on `HHSIZE` evaluates to 2. Is it the i>0 part? Do I need to use a repeat `for-loop` instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although you did pick your answer, could you provide `dput` of your `data.frame`,  to make your question reproducible. In this way you might, if possible, get more efficient and/or alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use rowSums and is.na(). No need for for loops here.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(HHSIZE=rowSums(across(5:19, ~!is.na(.x)))
```

An example with a tow data.frame:

```
#toy dataframe:

df<-data.frame(name=c('bob', 'mike', 'john'),
               member1=c(1,1,1),
               member2=c(2,1,NA),
               member3=c(1, NA, NA),
               member4=c(NA, NA, NA))
```

solution:

```
DF %>% mutate(HHSIZE=rowSums(across(2:5, ~!is.na(.x)))

  name member1 member2 member3 member4   HHSIZE
1  bob       1       2       1      NA        3
2 mike       1       1      NA      NA        2
3 john       1      NA      NA      NA        1
```

It can be done with a for loop too. Just create an empty numeric vector, then loop rowwise, and populate the vector with the sum of non-na elements of the desired columns in the dataframe (2:5 in my example):

```
output<-numeric()
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
        output[i]<-sum(!is.na(df[i, 2:5]))
}
df$HHSIZE<-output
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will try this now!

Comment: Please see that this solution actually provides what you want, as it is returning not the rowSums, but rather the sums of non-na elements (`rowSums ....... ~!is.na(.x)`) row-wise

Comment: `rowwise`/`c_across` variant: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(hhsize = sum(!is.na(c_across(2:5)), na.rm =TRUE))`

Comment: Yes, andrew_reece. This is less efficient, but works too. I think `na.rm=TRUE` is not needed though,

Comment: Just out of interest, is there a way to do this with loops as well?

Comment: I added a solution with a for loop

Comment: Everything that can be done with dplyr/purrr/*apply can eventually be done with loops too. These functions and packages just make everything more clear and less error-prone. Once you know the apply family and tidyverse well enought, you almost never use for loops again

Comment: Thanks very much for this GuedesBF! for learning's sake it's interesting to see the two different solutions (but I do I usually use tidyverse and I can see that for loops are inferior... )